# Force rotation without user knowing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiinterfaceorientation

My app allows a user to create an invoice. Data can be input in either landscape or portrait.

The user is then able to save the quote and view saved quotes in a collection view. Similar to Pages on iOS. The size of the tiles are the aspect ratio of the device in portrait view.

So if the user saves a quote I generate a screen shot of the view and save it so that it can be viewed in the tiled view (like iOS pages). This works all fine if the user saves when the device is in portrait. If they save while landscape it sucks.

So my question is, there a way I can rotate the view behind the scenes, generate a UIImage from it all without the user knowing noticing any orientation change.

Comment: Why not create a template view exactly as you want to save it (that may be the portrait view or another view, whatever) and then populate it with the data you want and render that to a UIImage and save it.  None of that has to even happen in the view stack.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about doing but it is fairly memory intensive to load the Invoice creation view. So I was wondering if there was a way around having to do that.

Comment: Terrible user experience? And yes I've heard about HTML. The invoice is not being printed or emailed. I am simply trying to create a thumbnail image of the invoice so the user has a graphical way to peruse saved invoices. Please read the question be providing a condescending answer. If you don't know Obj-c (which the question was tagged), please do not answer. @uchuugaka

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code that rotates it and takes a screenshot in the same thread then as long as you rotate it back before the thread finishes running, the device's screen will not update. Simply rotate everything (or if you have too many objects to rotate, take a screenshot of it all then rotate that screenshot) now take a screenshot of your new rotated view (or if you took a screenshot and rotated it don't do anything, you're done) then rotate everything back (again unless you just took a screenshot then rotated that)... If you need a screenshot method that can run in 1 thread use the CGContext code.

(To answer your question, rotating is always behind the scenes, it only becomes "in front" of the scenes when your thread ends... so if you rotate it back before the end of your thread the user will never see it because the device's screen will not update until after it has been rotated twice, there and back again.... bingo!)